# How to bring parsed files to a unique format

Tags: php, json, parsing, amazon-s3

I have different sources like S3 (json files) and API, and I have to bring all the data to a unique format to store the data in DB.

I tried to parse files and API response on my php back-end but it is too slow.
Is there some best practices or advises how I can do it in a right way?

I'm going to do an Interface with all required methods, and Class' for every source which will implement the Interface.

If I will work with hundreds or thousands files (per hour) Is this approach the best way to do it?

P.S. Currently the project is build on top of Symfony2 framework.

Comment: Added more details

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are forced my traditional RDBMS to convert all sources to specific format.

You may use schema-less systems like MongoDB, Cassandra or even JSON type in MySQL 5.7 to store 3 fields: id, source_type and source_json. This way you create several classes that know how to parse the source_type (ex: S3) and use them accordingly

Comment: thank you for your answer, but our client wants to see all the data stored in one table in unique format and probably to build something on top of this db table.

Comment: use Lumen with PHP7, run parallel parsers if pagination is provided by API